# My /var/www directory is full

Tags: debian, webserver, www

I am using Debian 7 on VirutalBox as my virtual web server. Now, my `/var/www` directory is almost full.

I added 27 GB of space to my VM as a new partition, formatted the partition with `ext4` but my `/var/www` directory still doesn't have enough space.
How can I resize `/var/www`?

The output of df -h:
[image]

Comment: Did you add the new space as a separate partition? Please post the output of `df -h`, `sudo fdisk -l` and `mount` when run on the virtual machine.

Comment: I don'T see your new 27G partition in there yet, have you added a mountpoint for it? (A way that might be useful to go is: mount to some temporary place, move contents of `/var/www` there, mount as `/var/www`.)

Comment: OK,the partition was there, it just wasn't mounted.
I mounted as you said ... works perfect :)
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the biggest partition appears to be `/home`, here is one solution (assuming there is no `/home/webpages` directory):

```
cd /var
cp -a www /home/webpages/
rm -fr www
ln -s /home/webpages/ www
```

What this does is:

- Enter the `/var/` direcotory
- Make an (as much as possible) exact copy of `/var/www` in the directory `/home/webpages`
- Complete destroy the contents of the `www` directory (to save disk space).  **rm -fr is a very dangerous command** Always use `rm -fr` with the utmost of care
- Make a symbolic link (symlink) so that /var/www now uses the files in `/home/webpages`

Now, sometimes web servers have issues with symlinks (I know Apache, in some configurations, refuses to follow a symlink), but, as I recall, this is not an issue if the document root (the directory the web server uses to publish files on the web) points to a symlink or if the symlink is below the document root.  But, if it is an issue, it may be necessary to set up Apache to allow symlinks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,a bigger partition was there it just had to be mountened.

Answer (score 0):

If you have freespace direct after your partition, you can resize the partition and then the filesystem on it using `resize2fs`